# Should outliers be removed only from the target variable or from any variable where they are found?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-cleaning, feature-scaling, outlier

What I often do is that I check boxplots and histograms for **target/dependent** variable and after much caution, treat/remove the outliers. But this is what I do only for the target variable. I.e., if considered the removal, I'd simply drop the entire row where my target value was found outlying.

Suppose if I am having outliers in some **independent variables** as well. What should I do there?

Either,

1. Should I ignore them?

Or,

2. Should I take the same approach with Independent variables as I took with the target variable?

EDIT:
Take the following example. Assume that we are predicting the expenditure of customers `target_expenditure_USD`. Other variables are Independent Variables

| age | sex | last_purchase | target_expenditure_USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | M | 12-02-2020 | 520,000 |
| 24 | F | 02-06-2019 | 2,234 |
| 43 | F | 10-08-2018 | 4,365 |
| 130 | M | 23-07-2020 | 1,424 |
| 45 | F | 12-01-1839 | 6,453 |

Thanks

Comment: How do you know they are outliers?

Comment: Assume if they are outliers. How should be they treated? i-e, in my independent variables as well

Comment: You shouldn't assume. If you are to edit your data you better have a good reason for doing so, otherwise you are better off using a robust model which is not susceptible to outliers.

Comment: I have given an example. Check it. It is a pretty naive attempt of creating an example haha. But suppose if I have such case

Comment: The point is that if you do not know the context of the data it is hard to tell what is "right" and what is "wrong". For your data, that poor soul who spent 520k dollars could have bought a house, hence the high expenditure. How would you know about this? If you were to remove this value and it was valid you would be biasing your data and results. If this was expenditure on candies you may reasonably well assume that it is indeed probably wrong, in that case, if your data allows it, drop the whole row, rather than changing the data.

Comment: Let's choose the latter case by assuming that it was meant to be expenditure on candies. and lets decide that the date from 1830s and an Age of 130 are invalid entries too.

Comment: Should I only remove the the row that has a bad target point, that $520K row OR should I also remove the rows consisting the date from 1830s and an Age of 130?

Comment: Now, the problem is that this was an incredibly simple (and nonsense) data example that I just made. 
In real cases, Should we probably be looking into every variable to find outliers OR we just need to look into the target variable?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comments.

You should inspect all variables for outliers, not just your dependent variable (y). And if you find any outliers then you should do something about it.

If you are certain that they are in fact erroneous measurements then ideally you would drop the whole row. If, however, you cannot determine that (and it doesn't look like it) then you shouldn't just drop them or change them, but rather it would be better to keep your data as-is, maybe mention the weird values, and use robust models when analyzing your data, that is models which are robust to outliers.